# How to sum up Cores with Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine

I have a bunch of VMs in Azure and would like to calculate the total amount of cores.

**Expecteted behaviour (for example):**

```
?> Get-TotalCores
?> 200
```

**Thats the Code:**

```
function Get-TotalCores {

    $TotalCores = $null
    $TotalWorkers = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Status | Where-Object { ( `
                $_.Name -notlike $MasterVM -and `
                $_.ProvisioningState -eq "Succeeded" ) }

    foreach ($Worker in $TotalWorkers) {
        $Size = (Get-AzVMSize -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -VMName $Worker.Name).HardwareProfile.VmSize
        $TotalCores += (Get-AzVMSize -location $Location | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $Size }).NumberOfCores
    }
    return $TotalCores
}
```

But my foreach loop is not able to getting the right SKU-Size. It seems, that

```
$Size = (Get-AzVMSize -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -VMName $Worker.Name).HardwareProfile.VmSize
```

is not able to fetch correct SKU.

Comment: Any update this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it this way

```
$TotalCores = $null
$ResourceGroup = "myawesomerg"
$TotalWorkers = (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Status | Where-Object { ( 
                $_.ProvisioningState -eq "Succeeded" ) })

foreach ($Worker in $TotalWorkers) {
    $VMSize = (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $Worker.Name).HardwareProfile.VmSize
    $Cores = (Get-AzVMSize -location $Location | Where-Object { $_.name -eq $VMSize }).NumberOfCores
    $TotalCores += $Cores
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the size of a specific VM, you need to use `Get-AzVM` instead of `Get-AzVMSize`.

```
$Size = (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "xxx" -VMName "xxx").HardwareProfile.VmSize
```

[image]